# HTML JS canvas inside div not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So, I'm trying to make a simple game with HTML/CSS/JS and there's a problem with canvas. My full code is at https://pastebin.com/DM2ChXR2 and it has a part like:

```
<div>
...
</div>
<p id="footer"></p>
__________
document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.getElementById("footer"));
```

Right now it works as expected, drawing canvas on top of all contents when the "start" button is pressed. But if I put the anchor tag inside the div like:

```
<div>
...
<p id="footer"></p>
</div>
```

then the canvas would not show up. I can't see the logical reason for that, what am I missing?

Comment: So, any errors in the console? Pastebin is not really helpful, it would be lots easier if you just create a [mcve] and post that code here

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the reason was improper usage of `insertBefore()`. Should have set up an id for div and used `document.getElementById("mainDiv").appendChild(this.canvas);` instead.

Comment: The true reason is that  the second param of `parentNode.insertBefore` must be a direct child of the `parentNode`. Here you moved `#footer` inside the div, which makes it no-more a direct child of `document.body`. You should have called `footer.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, footer)`. `div.appendChild` won't have the same effect.

Comment: Well, `appendChild()` works for me, because the footer is empty and I don't really need it. The visual result is identical.

Comment: :-) your canvas is absolutely positioned, and none of your other elements is, so you could append it literally anywhere in the document and "*The visual result* [would be] *identical*"... [Here it's in the button](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWt27QkMa0HyjkBpzhk3?p=preview), yep.

Comment: Well, that wasn't the final solution. Now I have it relative to the main div.